# moving average by date in mysql

Tags: mysql, moving-average

I want to retrieve a moving average of a cosumes table. I have written the following query but it doesn't work. It retrieves higher averages for the first days. What am I doing wrong?

```
select c.fecha, count(r.cantidad), avg(r.cantidad)
from 
(select distinct fecha
from tb_consumos
where fecha > '2015-02-01') c, tb_consumos r
where datediff(c.fecha, r.fecha)<10
 group by c.fecha
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct c.fecha, count(r.cantidad), avg(r.cantidad)
from tb_consumos c, tb_consumos r
where datediff(c.fecha, r.fecha)<10 
and c.fecha > '2015-02-01'
group by c.fecha
```

Comment: This dindn't work for me. 'distinct c.fecha' needs to be done previous to the cartesian product of cxr

Answer (score 0):

I had an error comparing dates, now is working:

```
select c.fecha, count(r.cantidad), avg(r.cantidad)
from 
(select distinct fecha
from tb_consumos
where fecha > '2014-02-01') c, tb_consumos r
where abs(datediff(c.fecha, r.fecha))<10
 group by c.fecha
```